# Using a variable URL value for Python HTTPConnection.request failing

Tags: python-3.x, yelp

I am trying to make an API call to Yelp's Fusion API. My calls work when hard coded. I am trying to get a list of businesses and then get a list of reviews for those businesses which requires two GETs. I'd like to step through the list of businesses and get their associated reviews. The following code results in a `Send a complete request to the server` message when using the variable form. Hard coding a business ID value works fine. Not sure what the challenge is. (Newbie question so my code is probably not the best either)

```
import http.client
import json

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.yelp.com")

headers = {
'authorization': "Bearer <access token value>",
'cache-control': "no-cache",
'postman-token': "<token value>"
}
#This request works fine
conn.request("GET", "/v3/businesses/search?latitude=40.8059518&longitude=-73.9657435&limit=10&radius=200&term=restaurant", headers=headers)

res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()

yelp_result = json.loads(data.decode("utf-8"))

all_businesses = []
for business in yelp_result['businesses']:
    b_name = business['name']
    b_id = business['id']
    rurl = "/v3/businesses/" + b_id + "/reviews"
    #This is the request resulting in error given earlier
    conn.request("GET",rurl,headers=headers)
    all_businesses.append((b_id, b_name))
```

Comment: So you're testing one hard-coded URL against a *completely different* variable URL, and you're not sure what's wrong.  So go step by step, simplify your code, print out the URLs, test them in a browser, etc.  This is not a question for us, you simply need to debug it.

Comment: Can you post examples of `b_id` and `rurl`?

Comment: Thanks @JohnZwinck for the hints and input. Using advice was able to learn that the conn.getresponse() call doesn't like to used without the corresponding conn.getresponse() and res.read() calls. Not entirely sure as to why but it works. Verified by commenting out these lines in the working version and reproducing earlier errors. (seems odd IMO, but whatever). Saw someone else was looking for help in another question on using the Yelp API with Python so took solution a little bit further in hopes it applies against that question too. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks @andrew_reece. Variable examples would be: `b_id = le-monde-new-york-3` and `rurl = /v3/businesses/le-monde-new-york-3/reviews`

Answer (score 0):

Challenge with the `conn.request` call seems to be that it also needs corresponding `conn.getresponse()` and `res.read()` calls. Doesn't like to open a connection if nothing is going to be done with it. (Would love it if someone had more insightful reason for this). Here's how to make a call to get limited number of businesses within a radius of a location (lat/long) and then also incorporate review snippets as part of that businesses info (not returned in the new Fusion API)

```
#My version of pulling a Yelp review around a particular business
#3 step proceedure
#   1. find all businesses around a location
#   2. convert to a dictionary with the key = business ID in Yelp
#   3a. request the reviews for the business ID, iteratively if necessary
#   3b. add reviews to the appropriate business as a list[0:2] of dict

import http.client
import json
# Step 1. Yelp API call to return list of businesses around a location
# for example, hard coded lat/long values used in conn.request call below. 
# Future functions: 
#    - dynamically create desired location. 
#    - number of businesses to return, current limit is 5 for testing
headers = {
    'authorization': "Bearer <access token value>",
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
    'postman-token': "<token value>"
}
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.yelp.com")
conn.request("GET", "/v3/businesses/search?latitude=40.8059518&longitude=-73.9657435&limit=5&radius=200&term=restaurant", headers=headers)
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()
yelp_result = json.loads(data.decode("utf-8")) #converts byte data to just text

# Step 2. convert to a dictionary with keys = business ID values
# Think the for loop below can be simplified. (Future effort)
biz2 = {}
for business in yelp_result['businesses']:
    b_id = business['id']
    biz2[b_id] = business

# Step 3. Request and adding reviews to appropriate business
for business in yelp_result['businesses']:
    b_id = business['id']
    r_url = "/v3/businesses/" + b_id + "/reviews"    #review request URL creation based on business ID
    #Step 3a. request the reviews for the business ID
    conn.request("GET",r_url,headers=headers)
    rev_res = conn.getresponse()     #response and read functions needed else error(?)
    rev_data = rev_res.read()
    yelp_reviews = json.loads(rev_data.decode("utf-8"))
    #Step 3b. add reviews to the appropriate business
    biz2[b_id]['reviews'] = yelp_reviews['reviews']

print(json.dumps(biz2, indent=3, separators=(',', ': ')))
```